# Toggle and hide using RXJs streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a sidebar menu using RX Js as an exercise. This is what I got so far:

```
var hideStream = Rx.Observable
.fromEvent(hideButton, 'click')
.map(() => false);

var toggleStream = Rx.Observable
.fromEvent(toggleButton, 'click')
.map(() => true);

var resultStream = Rx.Observable.merge(
toggleStream, hideStream)
.startWith(false)
.scan(function(value, newValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    return !value;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

The `toggleStream` observable listens to the hamburger and allows the user to toggle visibility of the menu. The second observable `hideStream` must be able to hide the menu no matter what the current state is.

This is working as intended, but I was wondering if there was a better way. What I did in the `scan` operator feels a bit odd to me...

Working example here: https://jsbin.com/hozozolune

Answer (score 1):

That looks quite alright to me, we can simplify things further when merging the hideStream and the toggleStream after the we have the toggleStream set up correctly:

```
var hideStream = Rx.Observable
.fromEvent(hide, 'click')
.mapTo(false);

var toggleStream = Rx.Observable
.fromEvent(toggle, 'click')
.mapTo(true)
.startWith(false)
.scan(value => !value);

var resultStream = Rx.Observable.merge(toggleStream, hideStream);
```